# Trying to find all tuples that match the max(count())) I have used

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a table with lets say two columns.

```
Owner | Letter |
------|--------|
John  |   A    |
John  |   B    |
John  |   B    |
Bob   |   B    |
Sam   |   A    |
Sam   |   B    |
```

I am trying to count the letter column and group it by the owners. I want to end up with the people who have the most distinct letters.
Like so:

```
Owner | Count |
----------------
John  |   2    |
Sam   |   2    |
```

I can get a count of all my letters grouped by owner but whenever I try to use max there seems to be no way to bring them together.

Here is what I have so far:

```
select owner 
from table
where (select count(distinct letter) from table group by owner) in 
(select max(count(distinct letter)) from table group by owner);
```

This query of course does not work because I am comparing two select statements I just cannot seem to figure out in what direction I'm supposed to be going. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why Sam has two distinct letters in your result? I believe that only John has two distinct letters for your sample data.

Comment: Sam has A and B as does John. John has two B's but that does not matter since I only want distinct values.

Comment: ok, now I get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` and `all` operator

```
SELECT owner, COUNT(distinct letter)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY owner
HAVING COUNT(distinct letter) >= ALL
(
  SELECT COUNT(distinct letter)
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY owner
)
```

Comment: the problem with this solution is it does not work for distinct. Say that Bob as two entries with the letter B in it. He would come out as the only answer.

Comment: @N.Poe ok, here: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=590b7e040f731bf06100dad6460366c1 is an example proving that my solution is correct for your data. Could you post counterexample? Thanks.

Comment: @N.Poe here: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=87dc1a05645e045f4bb5ae4e21d111c0 is an example with Bob having two B's, still the correct result ...

Comment: Oh wait you are right! This did end up working. Thank you Radim.

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as (
select owner,count(distinct letter) dl
from table
group by owner)
select t.*
from t
where (owner,dl) IN 
(select owner, max(dl) from t group by owner);
```

Comment: What kind of SQL dialect is this?

Comment: Correct @RadimBača I replaces = with IN

Comment: I think you have several other bugs (doubled `group`, missing `group`, `t1`)

Comment: Thanks very much @RadimBača! I think I corrected all bugs you mentioned. Very constructive attitude, cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

I originally misunderstood the question.  I would still use window functions:

```
select ol.*
from (select owner, count(distinct letter ) as cnt,
             rank() over (order by count(distinct letter) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by owner
     ) ol
where seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9401921770f7316a8a521fa329bf3785) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: If I try your solution: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cb3abb6a6634b28b80a4c3cc407d6a71 then it does not look even similar to the expected result.

Comment: @RadimBača . . . Thank you for putting together the SQL Fiddle.